# Django form validation not working after adding IntegerField with Radio Widget

Tags: django, django-forms, validationerror

I had my form set up and working with no errors, but after I added an IntegerFIeld with a RadioSelect widget the form no longer validates. (Before this I only had CharFields in the model and no widgets)

I've searched other similar questions but haven't been able to find anything to solve this issue.

At present I just keep getting the error message I coded in views.py.

My set up is as follows:

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404, redirect
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.contrib import messages
from django.utils import timezone
from .forms import DiaryEntryForm
from .models import DiaryEntry

def new_entry(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = DiaryEntryForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            entry = form.save(commit=False)
            entry.author = request.user
            entry.created_date = timezone.now()
            entry.save()
            messages.success(request, "Entry created successfully")
            return redirect(entry_detail, entry.pk)
        else:
            messages.error(request, "There was an error saving your entry")            
            return render(request, 'diaryentryform.html', {'form': form})
    else:
        form = DiaryEntryForm()
        return render(request, 'diaryentryform.html', {'form': form})
```

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from .models import DiaryEntry, FORM_CHOICES


class DiaryEntryForm(forms.ModelForm):
    body = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.RadioSelect(),choices=FORM_CHOICES)
    mind = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.RadioSelect(),choices=FORM_CHOICES)

    class Meta:
        model = DiaryEntry        
        fields = ('body', 'mind', 'insights')
```

**models.py**

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.conf import settings
from django import forms

# Create your models here.

FORM_CHOICES = [
    ('very bad', 'very bad'),
    ('bd', 'bad'),
    ('OK', 'OK'),
    ('good', 'good'),
    ('very good', 'very good'),
]

class DiaryEntry(models.Model):
    """
    Define the diary entry model here
    """

    author = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL) # link author to the registered user
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200) # set this to be the date later on
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    body = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True, choices=FORM_CHOICES)
    mind = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True, choices=FORM_CHOICES)
    insights = models.TextField()

    def publish(self):
        self.save()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title
```

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Well, what do you expect? An `IntegerField` expects an integer. Your choices are strings. You need a `CharField` in your model.

Comment: Of course!  What a silly mistake! Thank you so much for the help.

Comment: And learn how to use the debugger: It's so much easier to solve these kind of issues when you can actually see what's being posted by your form...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FORM_CHOICES` are strings. So you can't expect an `IntegerField` to validate with these choices.

- Either change your `FORM_CHOICES` to int values (e.g. (1, 'very bad'), (2, 'bad')...)
- Or change your model's `IntegerField` to a `CharField`.